# Pass variable to href tag within body of an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First time posting, although I have spent many a moon lurking around the site. I was unable to find if anyone had a similar post and thus I am posting to see if someone can answer this question for me.

I am trying to embed a hyperlink into the body of an email. I am taking data from a specific cell from a sheet

```
var n = ws.getRange("A2").getDisplayValue();
var data1 = ws.getRange("L2").getDisplayValue();
```

and want to pass that variable, *data1*,  to an html template to embed into a specific href tag URL within the template to mail out.

```
var temp= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("xyz");

temp.name = n;

var htmlMessage = temp.evaluate().getContent();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
      Email, 
      Subject,"Your email doesn't support HTML.", 
      {name: "AD", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );
```

Example html file "xyz":

```
<p>Hi, <?= name ?>,</p>

<p>Please see attached <a href="data1">link</a></p>
```

How would I go about passing the variable into the tag? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you accessing this HTML template...? Can you share your code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in accordance with the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines?

Comment: My fault. Updated the original post. Thanks!

Comment: In your script, how do you want to do about `name` of `<p>Hi, <?= name ?>,</p>`?

Comment: ```
var n = ws.getRange("A2").getDisplayValue(); 
var temp= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("xyz");
temp.name = n;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet and want to put the retrieved values to the HTML template. And, you want to use the HTML data at the HTML body of an email.
- In your question, you want to put a value of `data1` to `data1` of `<p>Please see attached <a href="data1">link</a></p>`.

I think that in your situation, the scriptlets of `<?= ... ?>` and `<?!= ... ?>` can be used. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### HTML side: `xyz.html`

```
<p>Hi, <?= name ?>,</p>

<p>Please see attached <a href="<?= data1 ?>">link</a></p>
```

- In this case, `<?= data1 ?>` or `<?!= data1 ?>` can be used.

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```
var n = ws.getRange("A2").getDisplayValue();
var data1 = ws.getRange("L2").getDisplayValue();

var temp= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("xyz");
temp.name = n;
temp.data1 = data1;
var htmlMessage = temp.evaluate().getContent();

GmailApp.sendEmail(
  Email, 
  Subject,"Your email doesn't support HTML.",
  {name: "AD", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
);
```

#### References:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets)
- [Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)

Answer (score -1):

Simply add a link in `href=""` like below

```
<p>Please see attached <a id="dataLink1" href="#">link</a></p>
<script>
var data1 = ws.getRange("L2").getDisplayValue();
document.getElementById("dataLink1").href=data1; 
</script>
```

Comment: This question is not about PHP